# Change URL of /blogs

Tags: nodes

How would I go about writing a function to change the url of */blogs* to */news*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the blog URL is hard coded, make an alias using the (core) [path module](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/path).